# MySQL Group by month using multiple date columns

Tags: sql, mysql

this is my first time asking a question here so I'll try to keep it clear!

Basically, I have a 3-part course that students can sign up for. I have a table of the students, with columns id, name, part_1_date, part_2_date, part_3_date. The date columns are of type DATETIME.

What I'm trying to do is run a select query that will return a new table with 12 rows, one for each month of the year. For each row, there should be a column for the name of the month, and then one column each for the number of times each "course part" was attended during that month.

For example, if my students table looks like this:

| id | name | part_1_date | part_2_date | part_3_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-15 |
| 2 | Jane | 2023-01-01 |  |  |
| 2 | Joe | 2023-02-02 |  | 2023-02-16 |

I would want the summary table to look like this:

| month | part_1_attendees | part_2_attendees | part_3_attendees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| February | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| March | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| April | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| June | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| July | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| August | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| September | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| October | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| November | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| December | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried searching Google for similar questions which led me to try a couple subqueries, but I couldn't find anything that quite worked the way I wanted it to. I did have success creating a summary table when I only had the month name and ONE of the course part attendance columns, but I couldn't figure out how to include all three course part columns in the same query and it involved me creating a separate table containing only the months of the year, which didn't feel ideal lol.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the months of the year:

```
with recursive months as (
    select 1 month_number, monthname(19700101) month_name
    union all
    select month_number+1, monthname(19700101 + interval month_number month)
    from months
    where month_number < 12
)
select * from months
```

Then you just need to join your students table and do conditional aggregation:

```
with recursive months as (
    select 1 month_number, monthname(19700101) month_name
    union all
    select month_number+1, monthname(19700101 + interval month_number month)
    from months
    where month_number < 12
)
select
    month_name,
    coalesce(sum(month(part_1_date)=month_number),0) part_1_attendees,
    coalesce(sum(month(part_2_date)=month_number),0) part_2_attendees,
    coalesce(sum(month(part_3_date)=month_number),0) part_3_attendees
from months
cross join students
group by month_number, month_name
order by month_number
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! One thing I should have clarified in my post is that this is not the first year I've done the course. I thiiiiink as it stands right now, the counts for each month are also including people who have attended that part in previous years. Is there a way to limit each number to only people who attended this year?

Comment: Ope, I actually think I got it! I just added an "and" to each of those coalesce lines. Thank you again!

Comment: @bradenjoshua yes (though make sure the and is *inside* the sum)